# Get all dates between provided dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table and sample data. I want to get the entire month's or specific dates attendance and information like hours he worked or days he was absent.

```
CREATE TABLE Attendance
(
    [EmpCode] int,
    [TimeIn] datetime,
    [TimeOut] datetime
)

INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-01 09:00:00', '2018-08-01 17:36:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-02 09:00:00', '2018-08-02 18:10:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-03 09:25:00', '2018-08-03 16:56:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-04 09:13:00', '2018-08-05 18:09:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-06 09:00:00', '2018-08-07 18:15:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-07 09:27:00', '2018-08-08 17:36:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-08 09:35:00', '2018-08-09 17:21:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-10 09:00:00', '2018-08-10 17:45:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-11 09:50:00', '2018-08-11 17:31:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-13 09:23:00', '2018-08-13 17:19:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-15 09:21:00', '2018-08-15 17:36:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-16 09:00:00', '2018-08-16 17:09:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-17 09:34:00', '2018-08-17 17:29:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-18 09:00:00', '2018-08-18 17:10:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-20 09:34:00', '2018-08-20 17:12:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-21 09:20:00', '2018-08-21 17:15:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-22 09:12:00', '2018-08-22 17:19:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-23 09:05:00', '2018-08-23 17:21:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-24 09:07:00', '2018-08-24 17:09:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-25 09:12:00', '2018-08-25 17:05:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-27 09:21:00', '2018-08-27 17:46:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-28 09:17:00', '2018-08-28 17:12:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-29 09:00:00', '2018-08-29 17:36:00');
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES (12, '2018-08-30 09:12:00', '2018-08-30 17:24:00');
```

I have a query that tells how many hours employee have worked, but it is only showing days on which data was present in table. I want to show all dates between provided dates and in case there is no data it should NULL in columns.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    [EmpCode],
    FirstIN    = CAST(MIN([TimeIn]) AS TIME), 
    LastOUT    = CAST(MAX([TimeOut]) AS TIME), 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), Datediff(second, CAST(MIN([TimeIn]) AS TIME), CAST(MAX([TimeOut]) AS TIME))/3600) 
       + ':'
       + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (Datediff(second, CAST(MIN([TimeIn]) AS TIME), CAST(MAX([TimeOut]) AS TIME)) % 3600) / 60), 2) 
       + ':' 
       + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Datediff(second, CAST(MIN([TimeIn]) AS TIME), CAST(MAX([TimeOut]) AS TIME)) % 60) , 2 ) AS HoursSpent,
    CAST(COALESCE(TimeIn, TimeOut) AS DATE) [Date]    
FROM Attendance
WHERE CAST(COALESCE(TimeIn, TimeOut) AS DATE) BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-08-25'    
GROUP BY EmpCode, TimeIn, TimeOut
```

Comment: Populate `Calendar` table and utilize it.

Comment: [The Calendar Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you need to use recursive way to generate possible dates :

```
with t as (
     select '2018-08-01' as startdt
     union all
     select dateadd(day, 1, startdt)
     from t
     where startdt < '2018-08-25'
)

select . . . 
from t left join
     Attendance at
     on cast(coalesce(at.TimeIn, at.TimeOut) as date) = t.startdt;
```

Just make sure to use date from `t` instead of `Attendance` table in `SELECT` statement.

Note : If you have a large no of date period, then don't forgot to use Query hint `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`, By defalut it has `100` recursion levels.

Comment: I'd personally go with a Tally if you can. If the OP is doing a much larger date range, then it'll have better performance than a rCTE. it also means there's no need for the the inclusion of `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`

Comment: @Larnu. . . I totally agreed with your hint, but sometime OP doesn't have create/alter rights to do these things. So, this would help as an alternative.

Comment: You can do a tally inside the query as well. Having a `VIEW` is nice, but not a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You May Try Recursive CTE to populate the Dates and Then Join With that to Get the Interval

```
DECLARE @From DATETIME = '2018-08-01' ,@To DATETIME= '2018-08-25'

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        [EmpCode] EmpId,
        MyDate = @From
        FROM Attendance A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        EmpId,
        MyDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,MyDate)
        FROM CTE
            WHERE MyDate < @To
)
SELECT
[EmpCode] = CTE.EmpId,
CTE.MyDate,
FirstIN    = CAST(MIN([TimeIn]) AS TIME), 
LastOUT    = CAST(MAX([TimeOut]) AS TIME), 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), Datediff(second, CAST(MIN([TimeIn]) AS TIME), CAST(MAX([TimeOut]) AS TIME))/3600) 
       + ':'
       + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (Datediff(second, CAST(MIN([TimeIn]) AS TIME), CAST(MAX([TimeOut]) AS TIME)) % 3600) / 60), 2) 
       + ':' 
       + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Datediff(second, CAST(MIN([TimeIn]) AS TIME), CAST(MAX([TimeOut]) AS TIME)) % 60) , 2 ) 

       AS HoursSpent,
CAST(CTE.MyDate AS DATE) [Date]

FROM CTE
    LEFT JOIN Attendance A
        ON A.EmpCode = CTE.EmpId
            AND CAST(CTE.MyDate AS DATE) = CAST(COALESCE(TimeIn, TimeOut) AS DATE)
GROUP BY CTE.EmpId, TimeIn, TimeOut,CTE.MyDate
    ORDER BY 6
```

Answer (score 1):

A different method, using a Tally Table. The advantage here is that an rCTE is a form of RBAR. The idea of a Tally table isn't as obvious, but is quicker, and also, won't need the `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` added if you have more than 100 days. in fact, this example handles up to 10,000 days, which shuold be more than enough:

```
DECLARE @EmpCode int = 12;

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1 --10
         CROSS JOIN N N2 --100
         CROSS JOIN N N3 --1000
         CROSS JOIN N N4 --10000
),
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, TT.MinTimeIn) AS CalendarDate,
           @EmpCode AS EmpCode
    FROM Tally T
         CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(CONVERT(date,TimeIn)) AS MinTimeIn,
                             MAX(CONVERT(date,TimeOut)) AS MaxTimeOut
                      FROM Attendance
                      WHERE EmpCode = @EmpCode) TT
     WHERE DATEADD(DAY, T.I, TT.MinTimeIn) <= CONVERT(date, TT.MaxTimeOut))
SELECT CalendarDate
       EmpCode,
       TimeIn,
       TimeOut
FROM Dates D
     LEFT JOIN Attendance A ON D.CalendarDate = CONVERT(date,A.TimeIn)
                           AND D.EmpCode = A.EmpCode;
```